# Can one rename a source file using Roslyn APIs?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, roslyn

I'm trying to write a `UnmatchedClassAndFilename` diagnostic and code fix using the new Roslyn and Visual Studio API's. The idea is to rename a class or filename in case they aren't equal.

How can I use the Roslyn API to rename a file in Visual Studio? The `Workspace` class doesn't seem to support this.

**Update:** Created an issue at CodePlex (https://roslyn.codeplex.com/workitem/258)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no current support for this in the Workspaces API. It's a common request but I'm not sure we have something explicitly tracking that work, so feel free to file the bug on [CodePlex](http://roslyn.codeplex.com).

Answer (score 0):

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and the Code Refactoring VSIX project template to accomplish this.

Here is my code:

```
private async Task<Solution> ConvertTypeNameToPascalCaseAsync(Document document, TypeDeclarationSyntax typeDecl, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Produce a PascalCased version of the type declaration's identifier token.
    var identifierToken = typeDecl.Identifier;
    var newName = identifierToken.Text.ToPascalCase();


    // Get the symbol representing the type to be renamed.
    var semanticModel = await document.GetSemanticModelAsync(cancellationToken);
    var typeSymbol = semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(typeDecl, cancellationToken);


    // Produce a new solution that has all references to that type renamed, including the declaration.
    var originalSolution = document.Project.Solution;
    var optionSet = originalSolution.Workspace.Options;
    var newSolution = await Renamer.RenameSymbolAsync(document.Project.Solution, typeSymbol, newName, optionSet, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    var newDocId = DocumentId.CreateNewId(document.Project.Id);
    var newText = await newSolution.GetDocument(document.Id).GetTextAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    // rename document by adding a new document with the new name and removing the old document
    newSolution = newSolution.AddAdditionalDocument(newDocId, newName + ".cs", newText);
    newSolution = newSolution.RemoveDocument(document.Id);

    // Return the new solution with the now PascalCased type name.
    return newSolution;
}
```

Note: `ToPascalCase()` is an extension method that I added to the string class.

The major point to notice is that I used `AddAdditionalDocument()` and `RemoveDocument()` to effectively rename the existing document to match my new name.

Here is the code that sets up the Code Refactoring engine:

```
public sealed override async Task ComputeRefactoringsAsync(CodeRefactoringContext context)
{
    var root = await context.Document.GetSyntaxRootAsync(context.CancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

    // Find the node at the selection.
    var node = root.FindNode(context.Span);

    // Only offer a refactoring if the selected node is a type declaration node.
    var typeDecl = node as TypeDeclarationSyntax;
    if (typeDecl == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (typeDecl.Identifier.Text.IsUpper())
    {

        // For any type declaration node, create a code action to reverse the identifier text.
        var action = CodeAction.Create("Convert type name to PascalCase", c => ConvertTypeNameToPascalCaseAsync(context.Document, typeDecl, c));

        // Register this code action.
        context.RegisterRefactoring(action);
    }
}
```

Note: `IsUpper()` is also an extension method that I added to the string class.

Incidentally, my specific use case is to convert all caps class names with underscores in them to PascalCased class names. Examples:

`TEST` = `Test`

`TEST_CLASS` = `TestClass`

`TEST_A_CLASS` = `TestAClass`

Comment: Nice to know that after 3 years there's a solution to this. If you decide to release this as an extension let us know!

Comment: I think you are going to want AddDocument not AddAdditionalDocument.  Additional documents are for things that are not source files, but can be used by analyzers and code fixes.